# $f(x) = \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$ can be expanded as a power series. What is the radius of convergence?

Tags: power-series

This question is off an exam I took. Naturally I set out to first to create a Maclaurin power series.

$f(x) = \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$ $\qquad \quad \quad \quad \quad  f(0)= 1$

$f'(x)= \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}$ $\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad f'(0)= 0$

$f''(x) = 2\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^3(x)} +\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$ $\quad f''(0)= 1$

Power series is then:

$$1 + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!}+...=\sum \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

I performed the ratio test on this power series and found that it converges everywhere.  However, my professor wrote that:

> The function $1/\cos x$ does not have a value
>   at $x = \pi/2$; therefore the inside of the circle or interval of convergence cannot include
>   $x = \pi/2.$ ” This point is a “singularity”, and no other singularity lies closer to the origin.
>
> This should be taken very seriously.*

What is this singularity he is referring to and why does it make my ratio test answer incorrect?

Comment: Cosine is zero at $\pi/2$ and your function will cause division by zero if you include that point

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=mclaurin+series+1%2Fcos(x)) disagrees with your power series.

Comment: So how does the pi/2 affect the interval of convergence?

Comment: You extrapolated poorly from the first few values of the derivative in attempting to find a power series. While your constant and $x^2$ terms are correct, it doesn't keep following the pattern that you assume.

Comment: Your power series is actually $\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you noticed in the derivatives does not continue at the 3rd derivative. The series for $ \frac{1}{\cos x} = \sec x $ is

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n} E_{2n}}{(2n)!} $$

where $E_n$ is the $n$-th [Euler number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerNumber.html). The radius of convergence is $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$.

Your professor's note is probably meant to be interpreted as,  "The fact that $f$ is undefined at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, but your series is should be a hint that you have the wrong series," or as @MiloBrandt pointed out below "the radius of convergence is the the distance to the nearest singularity in the complex plane, which is at $\frac{\pi}{2}$."

Comment: The professor's hint might also be noting radius of convergence equals the distance to the nearest singularity in the complex plane - that gives a much easier method for finding the radius of convergence. (At least, if this was in the context of complex analysis; it's not so clear from the question though)

Comment: @MiloBrandt yeah that makes more sense. For some reason I interpreted this as a Calc 2 question and responded as such.